# Read cell value in JTable while it is being edited

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Please guide me how can i read the value of jtable cell while it is in edit mode ( being edited). I have written above code in `keyTyped` event of jtable.

```
int col = tblItem.getSelectedColumn();
int row = tblItem.getSelectedRow();
try {
    float value =  Float.parseFloat(tblItem.getModel().getValueAt(row,2).toString());
    String str = new help.StringHelp().convertFloatString(value);
    tblItem.setValueAt(str + "", row, 2);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Suggest me how can i solve this issue.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am working on invoice application in which user types quantity of item . Everything goes well if user enter qty and press tab but if user skip the tab means enter qty and directly press save button then previous value of quantity is saved instead of new

Comment: Post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and directly press save button

So you need to stop editing on the cell before doing the Save.

You can either use:

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

when you create the table.

Or use:

```
if (table.isEditing())
     table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

in the `ActionListener` of your button.

Check out [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for more information.